# Generate member in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to extract the following page to a JSON object:

http://www.sarajevo-airport.ba/mobile/letovi.php?vrsta=odlasci&dest=Beograd&lang=bos

```
var mybody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var table = mybody.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var jsonObj = [];

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
{
    var cell2 = row.cells.length == '1' ? '' : row.cells[1].textContent.trim();
    jsonObj.push( { what: row.cells[0].textContent.trim(), value:cell2 });
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```

gets me to this JSON object

```
[
    Object { what= "Beograd" , value= "" }, 
    Object { what= "Broj leta" , value= "JU 109, JA 1376" }, 
    Object { what= "Avio-kompanija" , value= "JAT AIRWAYS" }, 
    Object { what= "Tip aviona" , value= "AT72" }, 
    Object { what= "Planirano vrijeme" , value= "06:20" }, 
    Object { what= "Status leta" , value= "Odletio" }, 
    Object { what= "" , value= "" }, 
    Object { what= "Beograd" , value= "" }, 
    Object { what= "Broj leta" , value= "SOP 4121" }, 
    Object { what= "Avio-kompanija" , value= "SOLINAIR LTD" }, 
    Object { what= "Tip aviona" , value= "SF34" }, 
    Object { what= "Planirano vrijeme" , value= "16:35" }, 
    Object { what= "Status leta" , value= "Odletio" }, 
    Object { what= "" , value= "" }
]
```

since this page contains info about 2 flights 
I need to add two elements in JSON string describing

1. flight1
2. flight2

So how can I get something like this:

```
 {  "Flight1": [
    Object { what= "Beograd" , value= "" }, 
    Object { what= "Broj leta" , value= "JU 109, JA 1376" }, 
    Object { what= "Avio-kompanija" , value= "JAT AIRWAYS" }, 
    Object { what= "Tip aviona" , value= "AT72" }, 
    Object { what= "Planirano vrijeme" , value= "06:20" }, 
    Object { what= "Status leta" , value= "Odletio" }, 
    Object { what= "" , value= "" }],

"Flight2": [
    Object { what= "Beograd" , value= "" },     
    Object { what= "Broj leta" , value= "SOP 4121" }, 
    Object { what= "Avio-kompanija" , value= "SOLINAIR LTD" }, 
    Object { what= "Tip aviona" , value= "SF34" }, 
    Object { what= "Planirano vrijeme" , value= "16:35" }, 
    Object { what= "Status leta" , value= "Odletio" }, 
    Object { what= "" , value= "" ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is not a valid JSON element.

You can validate your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing, is creating basic javascript objects. By the way you can do this:

```
var jsonObject = {}; // create object
jsonObject["foo"] = ["a", "b"]; // create associative indexes, so called members
jsonObject.bar = {}
jsonObject.something = 10;
```

to serialize it to JSON, your best option is `JSON.stringify()`, which converts your js objects to a JSON string, and `jQuery.parseJSON()`, which converts a JSON string back to a js object. You will need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to use these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the `<hr>` element to iterate through your objects:

```
var mybody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var table = mybody.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var jsonObj = [], flights = {}, numFlights = 1;

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
{
    if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "<hr>") {
        flights["Flight"+(numFlights++)] = jsonObj;
        jsonObj = [];
    }
    else {
       var cell2 = row.cells.length == '1' ? '' : row.cells[1].textContent.trim();
       jsonObj.push( { what: row.cells[0].textContent.trim(), value:cell2 });
    }
}
console.log(flights);
```